# force:recordData getNewRecord( DYNAMIC recordTypeId )

Tags: lightning-aura-components, controller, slds

How can I get the function getNewRecord() to take a variable as the record Type ID? I'm in a different scratch org and I don't want to have to keep going through and finding the specific recordTypeID.

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    //Get Record Type Id of Anticipated
    String devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Invention__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Anticipated').getRecordTypeId();

    //Prepare new record from template        
    component.find("inventionRecordCreator").getNewRecord(
        "Invention__c", // sObject Type (entityAPIName)
        devRecordTypeId, //recordTypeID
        false, //skip cache?
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            var rec = component.get("v.newInvention");
            var error = component.get("v.newInventionError");
            if(error || (rec === null)) {
                console.log("Error initializing record template: " + error);
            }else{
                console.log("Record template initialized: " + rec.sobjectType);
            }
        })
    );

}
```

I have tried saving devRecordTypeId as an Id and as a String. I get the error

> Parsing error: Unexpected token devRecordTypeId

Worth noting this code worked perfectly fine until I changed scratch orgs. (The code above was edited given the problem, and originally did not have devRecordTypeId as the value was explicitly given).

---

Solution verified. Thank you @Keith C

```
//Get Record Type Id of Anticipated
    var devRecordTypeId = component.get("c.getRecordTypeId");
```

Controller:

```
//Get Record Type ID
public static String getRecordTypeId() {
    Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Invention__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Anticipated').getRecordTypeId();
    return devRecordTypeId;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
String devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Invention__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Anticipated').getRecordTypeId();
```

looks like Apex code and so will not execute as JavaScript. You can execute that in a server side method and return its value; not sure if there is an easier way to get the value in Lightning Component JavaScript.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I will edit the post to reflect the answer. Thank you.